# Get color at location in LinearGradient

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to build a gradient with LinearGradient and then access it's color at a certain location along its stops?

Example:

```
LinearGradient gradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue],
  stops: [0.0,100.0,200.0],
);
```

If there were a method like `getColor(double)` it might work like this

```
gradient.getColor(100.0) // returns equivalent to Colors.green
gradient.getColor(150.0) // returns interpolated color between green and blue
```

I am trying to use Flutter's ability to generate gradients to give me interpolated colors at specific values.

*edit*

```
Color lerp(Color a, Color b, double t);
```

allows you to blend colors using the same logic as a gradient, but it does not allow you to blend over list of colors

Comment: FYI - your stops are incorrect according to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/Gradient/stops.html). They should be in the range `0.0 --> 1.0`

Comment: Thank you. I missed that. I will probably have to make a custom class to handle those wider extents then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess using `lerp`, the array of colors and the array if stops, you can easily build that function. Something like this:

```
Color lerpGradient(List<Color> colors, List<double> stops, double t) {
  for (var s = 0; s < stops.length - 1; s++) {
    final leftStop = stops[s], rightStop = stops[s + 1];
    final leftColor = colors[s], rightColor = colors[s + 1];
    if (t <= leftStop) {
      return leftColor;
    } else if (t < rightStop) {
      final sectionT = (t - leftStop) / (rightStop - leftStop);
      return Color.lerp(leftColor, rightColor, sectionT);
    }
  }
  return colors.last;
}
```

Comment: It only supports `ltr` or `rtl` gradients. What about skewed gradients?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is by using `TweenSequence`.

```dart
const _colors = [
    Color(0xFFE54872),
    Color(0xFFF76808),
    Color(0xFF6E56CF),
];

static final _tween = TweenSequence(
    [
      for (var i = 0; i < _colors.length - 1; i++)
        TweenSequenceItem(
          tween: ColorTween(
            begin: _rainbowColors[i],
            end: _rainbowColors[i + 1],
          ),
          weight: 1.0,
        ),
    ],
);
```

And then use `transform` or `evaluate`.

```dart
final color = _tween.transform(time);
```